# How to block permission in xslt through security:hasPermission

Tags: xslt

In below code the requirement is need to restrict permission for all the user.
i.e security:hasPermission we need to restrict.

```
<xsl:if test="security:hasPermission('CollectionMemberInsert')">
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li onclick="qbo3.getObject(this).popup('Theme.ashx/Render?Transform=Templates/Contact/CollectionMember.Popup.xslt&amp;SourceObject=Attachment', {{addIds: true, method: 'CollectionMemberInsert', Title: 'Add Tag'}});">
                    <a>
                      <i class="icon-tag"></i>
                      <xsl:text> Add Tag</xsl:text>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </xsl:if>
```

Comment: What XSLT engine are you using? XSLT doesn't have "permissions" by default, its just a transformation language.

Comment: He's using a C#-based framework Quandis Business Object (QBO3). We provide a handful of C# XSLT extension objects, including a security extension that provides the feature he's using.

Answer (score 1):

The QBO3 infrastructure includes several [XSLT extension objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf741884.aspx), including one to access security settings.

You are using the standard QBO3 XSLT security extension correctly in the example you cite. Ensure that you perform your unit test after clearing the security cache (Theme.ashx/Recycle).